# getCredentialsForIdentity - ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create a cognito identity pool, assign roles to it & get credentials from the created identity pool. But for some reason it fails to find the identity pool resource created with error -

> { ResourceNotFoundException: Identity 'us-east-2:9b1d5236-c8e1-40f5-ab44-9968101c3fde' not found.}

I have the code sample attached & I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have looked around with no success.
Thanks.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({apiVersion: '2014-06-30'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    var params = {
        AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: false, /* required */
        IdentityPoolName: 'admin_pool', /* required */
        CognitoIdentityProviders: [
            {
            ClientId: '6m1sp69cptu5e5j7ve3arknkjgm',
            ProviderName: 'cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/us-east-2_OAAtfnU3c3',
            ServerSideTokenCheck: false
            }
        ]
    };

    cognitoidentity.createIdentityPool(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else {
            var idpid = data.IdentityPoolId;
            console.log(data);           // successful response
            let params = {
                IdentityPoolId: data.IdentityPoolId, /* required */
                Roles: { /* required */
                    'authenticated': 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/cc_admin',
                    'unauthenticated': 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/Cognito_admin_poolUnauth_Role'
                }
            };

            cognitoidentity.setIdentityPoolRoles(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                else {
                    console.log('retval:' + JSON.stringify(data));           // successful response

                    var params = {
                        IdentityId: idpid
                    };

                    cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
                        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: I think you're saying that your code creates a pool and then you use the returned pool ID to set roles for that pool but the set roles call fails with invalid pool ID. Perhaps this is a timing/eventual consistency type of issue. Can you implement (exponential) backoff and retry around the 'set roles' call?

Comment: No, it fails in getCredentialsForIdentity(). The logs show me that. - 


"CognitoIdentityProviders: 
   [ { ProviderName: 'cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/us-east-2_OAAtfnU3c3',
       ClientId: '6m1sp69cptu5e5j7ve3arknkjgm',
       ServerSideTokenCheck: false } ] }
2018-06-06T02:08:11.901Z 75a9e297-692e-11e8-86fc-3f019c79abb1 retval:{}
2018-06-06T02:08:12.007Z 75a9e297-692e-11e8-86fc-3f019c79abb1 { ResourceNotFoundException: Identity 'us-east-2:8910b6e8-61c6-4eff-bd06-1ac0e79964a1' not found."

Comment: Aren’t you supposed to get credentials for the ID of an identity that’s in the pool, rather than for the pool ID itself?

Comment: Yes, that epiphany just hit me. AWS doc confused me. It describes identity ID as - "A unique identifier in the format REGION:GUID". I mistook that for identity pool id. Thanks for the help!